# File handle segfault

Tags: c, networking, segmentation-fault

Implementing a data link protocol. I managed to send the whole file through the virtual serial port - which should be the hard part. The weird thing is I'm getting a segfault on fclose() when trying to save it. The file is being created, which means the open is successful, but nothing it being stored in it. Even changed the implementation to buffer all the file into memory before saving it.

```
int app_rx(const char* outputFile){
    file_data_t fileData;
    if(!receive_ctrl_pckt(&fileData)){
        printf("Could not receive control packet\n");
        return FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Receiving file [%s]\nFile size: %d\n", fileData.fileName, fileData.fileSize);
    unsigned char fileBuffer[fileData.fileSize];
    int fileIndex = 0;
    int totalBytes = 0;
    int stop = 0;
    size_t sqNo = 0;
    int bytes;
    FILE* out = fopen(outputFile, "w");
    do{
        activeBuffer = (activeBuffer + 1) % 2;
        printf("Receiving packet %lu\n", sqNo);
        bytes = llread(BUFFERS[TMP_BUFFER]);
        if(bytes == DUP_ERR){
            printf("Duplicate data. Discarding packet\n");
        }
        else if (bytes == WH_ERR){
            printf("Invalid header. Discarding packet\n");
        }
        else if (bytes == WD_ERR){
            printf("Corrupted data. Awaiting retransmission\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Packet %lu successfully received\n", sqNo);
            int retrieveRes = retrieve_payload(sqNo);
            switch(retrieveRes){
                case CTRL_END: {
                    stop = 1;
                    break;
                }
                case FAILURE: {
                    printf("Unknown error\nExiting...");
                    exit(1);
                }
                case SQ_ERR:{
                    printf("Unsynchronized packets\nExiting");
                    exit(1);
                }
                default:{
                    for(int i = 0; i < retrieveRes; i++){
                        fileBuffer[fileIndex] = BUFFERS[activeBuffer][i];
                        fileIndex++;
                    }
                    sqNo = (sqNo + 1) % 255;
                    totalBytes += bytes;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }while(!stop);
    printf("file index: %d\n", fileIndex);
    fwrite(fileBuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), fileIndex, out);
    printf("here\n");
    fclose(out);
    if(totalBytes == fileData.fileSize){
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    else{
        return FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Stdout:

```
Packet 9 successfully received
Receiving packet 10
Asserting data integrity
Packet 10 successfully received
Receiving packet 11
Asserting data integrity
Packet 11 successfully received
file index: 10968
here
make: *** [Makefile:35: run_rx] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Giant method, I know. Just trying to get it under before refactoring properly. Can't for the sake of nothing figure out what's going on. I know this works because I've copied the exact same file using this method with a simple copyfile.c test driver which mimics the cp command.

Any ideas? I find it particularly odd that it creates the output file, but doesn't write anything on it.

EDIT: managed to get it going by opening the file right before writting to it. Still don't quite understand what happened

Comment: What is the link between `TMP_BUFFER` and `active_buffer` ? There's probably a stack overflow somewhere in the code, but not necessarly in the part you put here.

Comment: TMP_BUFFER is being used to read from the file to be sent and buffer the data before attaching the required header. The packet that'll be sent is then stored in active_buffer and sent to the data link layer. Felt like the cleanest way to implement the protocol. I'm using 3 1024 byte buffers, shouldn't overflow from that... Although maybe the dynamic allocation in the data link might be messing it. Will implement it properly

Answer (score 1):

There is a potential buffer overflow risk for array fileBuffer, except that retrieveRes is guaranteed smaller or equal than fileData.fileSize, if there is a buffer overflow, pointer out may be overwritten and caused a segment fault when call fclose. The buffer overflow can be verified by print the value of out before do/while loop and call to fclose.